# Creating a monotonic function

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I have $n$ functions $f_i(x) \{i = 1 ,...,n\} $that does not preserve the monotonic mapping order.

i.e. if $x_1 < x_2$, then in general, $f_i(x_1)$ is not less than $f_i(x_2)$ (for all $i = 1 ... n$)

Can I construct a function $g$ mapping on $f_i$'s such that $g(f_1, f_2, ... f_n)$ is monotonic?

If yes, please elaborate on the method for the same.

Even if $g$ is a unimodal function, it should be fine.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do we have $g:R^n \to R$? It seems you can pick $g$ constant if you do not care your function being strictly increasing. But even so, is there a restriction on $g$ such as continuity?

Comment: Yes, $g$ maps to $R$.
I do not know the mapping of $f_i$ from $x$ (some physical process).
I am hoping to estimate $x$ starting from $f_i$ of some unknown $x$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand at all what you want to do. Please give your problem, not just your attempt at solving it

Comment: For every value of $x$ over an interval, I have the ($n$) outcomes of some physical process denoted by $f_i$ ($i$ = 1 to $n$). 

Now given a set of $f_i$'s corresponding to an unknown value of $x$  (but known to lie within the interval), I have the task of estimating $x$. 

Since these $f_i$'s are not monotonic in nature (no set pattern), I felt it would aid in the estimation task if I could construct a monotonic function $g$ using the $f_i$'s.